# Assets - "The file cannot be found" error

Tags: channel-entries, assets, control-panel

We have a few entries that work well on the live site, but when editing on staging server we get the following error:

An Error Was Encountered
The file cannot be found

This might be the same issue as this question:
[Editing entry in backend: "The file cannot be found"](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/35566/editing-entry-in-backend-the-file-cannot-be-found)
but I can't comment so I decided to open a new one.

We did a text search through the entire EE files and the only one with that exact text string ("the file cannot be found") was Assets. We tried updating the addon, updating databases, double checking all files to make sure nothing was missing.

We could copy the contents from the db as the other question suggests but we'd rather have this fixed so it doesn't happen again. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Santiago

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case it's useful for someone else:

This particular issue was triggered by a missing file on the upload folder. The file was related to the entry via an Assets field and most likely for human error it got removed from our server. We restored the file and the entry was editable again.

Comment: For me it was a brackets in the file name of an image field in the entry. The entry was able to be created but the error occurred when trying to edit the entry.