# Getting 404 error when trying to access Content > Edit in v2.10.3

Tags: ee2, 404, admin

I'm getting a 404 error when trying to go to *Content > Edit* via the admin, as well as *Content > Edit > My Channel*.

EE v2.10.3

Installed Extensions:

[image]

**The error:**

> 404 Page Not Found
>   The page you requested was not found.

It may be related to this issue: [Editing entry in backend: "The file cannot be found"](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/35566/editing-entry-in-backend-the-file-cannot-be-found), however I cannot access the *Content > Edit* area of the admin at all, it's not just one particular entry.  This is also a new install with very little content / entries created so far.

I've tried:

- Disabled all extensions (no change)
- Enabled all debugging (nothing more is output on the error page)
- Edited the /expressionengine/libraries/Mime_type.php as mentioned in the above link (this did not change the error message for me and I didn't not get a file path)
- Re-uploading all EE core files (no change)

I found the file that is outputting the error message at /codeigniter/system/core/Exceptions.php and it says:

> // By default we log this, but allow a dev to skip it

I couldn't find the error logged anywhere though.  And developer log just has 3 errors for `add_to_head()` being deprecated (which I've seen in other installs and hasn't caused any issues):

[image]

Any ideas what could be causing this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EE Support fixed this for me (yay!). It turns out the **/system/expressionengine/controllers/cp/content_edit.php** file was blank - though I had uploaded the core files twice... nonetheless, answering this in case anyone else runs into the issue or similar.